# How to Integrate Two Piwiks

Tags: integration, matomo

We are having Two **Piwik** analytical tools to track (both are same version), in two different OUs.

Now we are planning to integrate both as one Global Piwik instead of two, Could you please suggest us the best processt o proceed on this.

Thank you!

Comment: There is a chapter in the manual about using mutliple trackers: https://developer.piwik.org/guides/tracking-javascript-guide#multiple-piwik-trackers

Comment: Thank you! I have checked your suggested link,
Sorry,If I made confusion with my above words,the requirement is:Ex:
1) We have installed Piwik in two different servers,consider Server-I (Here Piwik-X is tacking some 100 configured sites with site IDs:1-100) & Server-II (Here also Piwik-Y is tacking some 10 configured sites with site IDs:1-10)
2) It means complete two different Piwik setups are in two different servers with respected DB
3) Now we want move Piwik-Y from Server-II to Server-I in future only one Piwik-X with 110 sites
4)How to integrate these X&Y Piwiks?Both versions are same

Comment: In this case i think this fits better: https://plugins.piwik.org/SiteMigration

Comment: Thank you! started analyzing the same ,As per the analysis : 
Consider (Piwik-Y in App Server-II is **source** ,Piwik-X in App Server-I is **target** ) 

1) As per my understanding, Plugin has to install in source App server and run the **console command** in same App server, while running have to provide the respected target **App DB Server and name details**? **Could you please confirm this.**

After this,site Id will be changing(I mean,101..go on to Piwik-X), it mean Piwik-Y existing site users have to compromise with site Id,by editing tracking code,
Please correct me If I`m wrong.

Comment: You are correct, but additionally Server-II (the plugin) needs to have access to the MySQL server on Server-I and keep in mind that this plugin is by a third party and hasn't been updated since Nov 2015 so neither piwik nor me can guarantee that it will work correctly.

Comment: Thank you! We are In-Progress of testing this methodology, will letting you know once we done.

Comment: Hi, Is there any way to know the Piwik, Master and Transaction table in detailed or any mechanism to get the ER diagram of all the details.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to migrate single sites from one piwik instance to another is the (third party) plugin [SiteMigration](https://plugins.piwik.org/SiteMigration).

You need to be able to use the php cli on the source server and the source server needs to have MySQL access on the target server.

Comment: We are checking on this, I could say we reached one step ahead, One QQ : while integrating site, whether this tool would integrate history of the site from Source server along with site integration. If not its very impact on integration, If you would have update could you please share with us, It would a great help.